# Visual Studio 2015 crashing intermittently

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2015

I'm running

> Visual Studio Professional 2015
>
> Version 14.0.23107.0.D14REL
>
> Windows 10

It crashes/restarts intermittently, even when I am not working on it but just have it open. I have googled this, there are similar issues but these posts refer to the RTM build and are special cases.

Has anyone heard/experienced this? Any ideas?

TIA

--- EDIT/UPDATE ----

I have more data. Running VS 2015 in SAFE MODE with logging. I'm not doing anything with it, just letting it sit. Eventually it will crash and restart.

I found a pair of errors in my Event Log. Turns out they are always in pairs when this happens. I just can't make out what this means. I think I've googled just about everything on this and find nothing related to what I'm experiencing. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

FIRST ERROR LOG ENTRY

```
.NET Runtime  EventID 1026
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  .NET Runtime 
  - EventID 1026 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 0 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
  [ SystemTime]  2015-08-28T22:07:08.000000000Z 
   EventRecordID 14935 
   Channel Application 
   Computer mdad
    Security 
 - EventData 

   Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException Stack: at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c__DisplayClass2.<ThrowAsync>b__5(System.Object) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

SECOND ERROR LOG ENTRY

```
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Application Error 
  - EventID 1000 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 100 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
  [ SystemTime]  2015-08-28T22:07:08.000000000Z 
   EventRecordID 14936 
   Channel Application 
   Computer mud-dad 
   Security 
- EventData 
  devenv.exe 
   14.0.23107.0 
   559b7ead 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   10.0.10240.16384 
   559f3b2a 
   e0434352 
   000b3e28 
   4330 
   01d0e1d57b904f45 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   9ead8f6c-f423-49a1-aa5a-937c1bfde37e
```

---- EDIT/UPDATE ----

The crash/restart of VS2015 occurs every hour from the time I start it. I have gone through all of the settings to look for something that might be set to happen on a schedule. I disabled Auto Recover and Check for Updates but that didn't fix fix it. I was able to anticipate the next crash. At least I have a pattern which should help identifying the problem. If anyone has any ideas on where else I might look, please post.

Comment: Between VS2016, VS2015 and VS2005, it is probably confused what it should be.  Surely you can do a better job asking this question.

Comment: You can attach a debugger to Visual Studio, e.g. WinDbg.

Comment: The crash occurs every hour from the time I start VS2015. I've updated the description with that info. Trying to find what might be happening every hour. It's something within VS2015 (not my computer) because it on the hour from the time I start VS2015.

Comment: i had the same issue. what fixed for me is running: devenv.exe /resetuserdata   see this link,there are other possible fixes mentioned: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd243ee7-d72b-40f6-9588-705b5cbccc6d/visual-studio-crashingrestarting-every-hour?forum=vssetup

Comment: Do you run VS2015 as admin? If not, it would be interesting to know if the crash still happens when you run as admin (although I'm not saying that that should be the solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a complete reinstall fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply try : **devenv.exe /resetuserdata** instead of reinstalling the whole program

Comment: This helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening every hour is that it is trying to download content. Check your settings. I am still using VS 2005, for me that would be Options, Environment, Startup.

Comment: Disabling "Download Content Every X minutes" (which was set to 60) fixed this problem for me. Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: I dont know why this answer has been downvoted so many times... Anyway it solved the issue for me also on Win10 VS2015

Comment: I have disable "Download Content Every X minutes" but still not fixed problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue, but finally happened upon a workaround on the "Visual Studio 2015 fixed bugs and known issues" page (link below).  Apparently it was my lack of permissions to the VSRemoteSettings folder within a temporary directory that was causing the UnauthorizedAccessException on my box.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135